# SharePoint 2010 returning 404 favicon.ico

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm troubleshooting a SharePoint 2010 404 issue when attempting to access a web application using an elevated user account.  The account I am using is the Farm Setup account which is local and domain admin as well as admin on sql.

The server is 2012 RT with all the Windows updates applied and the SharePoint Build number is the 14.0.7162.500 which is the December 2015 release.

Upon first accessing the my site web I am immediatly prompted for user name and password which I enter. The prompt is repeated a number of times usually resulting in a Unauthorized notice.  Sometime, however after a few repeated login attempts the page miraculously displays.

Using Fiddler I can see the repeated logins resulting in 404 on the /favicon.ico file [log linked here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=97E3C4B2C3B90E23!377474&authkey=!AOeWqKCD-tpW-J0&ithint=file%2Csaz).

I am hoping someone has seen this behvior before and can help me fix it.

Comment: the account is local... where is the browser? RDP to the server usign that local account, and browse from there, my guess is the error wont be there anymore. if the account is local, how come is alse admin in SQL? ummm you have SharePoint installed on the same server as the SQL Server? o.O that would not be good.